# how to make a video appear without zooming in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a video gallery but the videos only show when I zoom in.
You are able to hear it, but not see it when it's zoomed out. I don't know
how to allow it to show.

[This is what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSGA0.png)

To see the video when it's zoomed out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.